# Trying to Get the next department number from dept table using SQL Function

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets assume that we have a Department Table that has DEPTNO with the values (10,20,30,40...etc ) 
How can i create a function that get the next department number ?
I was studying it and i think if im not right that the function should contain sequence , still not sure , need your help guys .

Solving this will let me learn how the functions work so if thats ok explain how the code can be , thank you so much .

Comment: You mean your table contains departments 10, 20, 30, and 40, so you want a function that gives you 50 (i.e. max deptno + 10)?

Comment: Kind of , lets assume that the current dept no is 10 it should return 20 and so on

Comment: Kind of? So how is this different from what I say? You have deptnos in your table and you want the maximum one + 10. Or not? Is it not about what you have in your table? Is it: give me 10 now, no matter what I do with it, give me 20 next time? Regardless of what's really in the table? Or what else?

Comment: My bad sorry , read your reply wrong , i was confused . yea exactly just like what you said . sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the numbers like that in the table is not easy. You can select the maximum and add 10. But what if two people working with the database want to insert a new department at the same time? They both get the same maximum number, say 20, add ten, and try to insert the same ID 30.

Oracle has sequences for that. When two people draw the next sequence number, one has to wait for the other, so one gets the next number 30 and the other the number following, i.e. 40. But when one dismisses their insert with rollback, then the ID is not in the table. You could get records 10, 20, 40 for instance.

I think it's also possible to lock the whole table, then select the maximum, insert that value + 10 and commit and release the table.

Most people simply use a sequence. And they don't care about gaps. They don't even care about what the numbers look like as long as they are unique. They use them for technical IDs, which only exist to be able to relate tables; they have no meaning. A department number on the other hand would be a business attribute. It would not be the database finding a value, but some person ("Hey folks, we establish a second buying department and call it B2"). So the wohle case isn't realistic. Anyway:

Here is a sequence you could create:

```
create sequence seq start with 10 increment by 10;
```

And here is how to use it:

```
insert into dept (deptno, name) values (seq.nextval, 'Buying 2');
```

You can also have a trigger get that sequence value on insert, or as of Oracle 12c use it as the default value for deptno.

And here is a function selecting the max deptno and returning this plus 10:

```
create or replace function next_deptno return integer
as
  v_max_deptno integer;
begin
  select coalesce(max(deptno), 10)
  into v_max_deptno
  from dept;

  return v_max_deptno + 10;
end next_deptno;
```

Comment: Wow your answer is so amazing , to the point that it did answer another Q that i was looking for answer for it and its related to the sequence , so i want to thank you so much for it and just cant say more than wow . Thank you again sir =)